# Variables in my Service/IntentService are reset on every start

Tags: android, variables, constructor, android-service, intentservice

I declared a service, that shall act as a queue. Therefore I have a variable that tells the service it's the first start and another one that stores a value.

The code looks like this:

```
public class TTSQueue extends Service {

private Integer lastvol = 0;
private Boolean isFirstStart = true;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    Integer vol = b.getInt(TTS.PARAM_LAST_VOL, 0);
    if (vol > lastvol) {
        lastvol = vol;
    }
    if (isFirstStart) {
        isFirstStart = false;
        startAnotherService();
    } else {
        waitForAnEventAndThen_startAnotherService();
    }

}
```

Okay, the problem is, this Service is started from a receiver. And everytime it is started, both `lastvol` and `isFirstStart` are reset. I thought, if the Service is already created and then started with an Intent, it would only call `onStartCommand()` again and not reset everything.

I also tried only declaring the variables and setting them to the default value in `onCreate()`, but that had the same effect.
Also I tried replacing the `Service` with an `IntentService`, but that doesn't help either, same problem.

I would like to avoid using `SharedPreferences`, as I don't think it is necessarily needed in this case. (And I don't want to waste the user's Write Cycles).

Am I missing something? I guess it is not because of the `private` declaration, is it?

Comment: Marc from Duetchland! I have no idea, but I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This surely does not have anything to do with members being private.

I'm not sure what's the problem, but I could imagine one of these candidates:

- The service terminates before a second request arrives.
- The `Receiver` spawns a new process because it responds to a "system intent".

You could evaluate this guesswork by letting your service log something periodically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the reason was really that the service was terminated. Weird. But it is working now, thanks!